# Is there any NDK equivalent on iOS?

Tags: ios

I came from Android and have no idea if this can be done on iOS.

A portion of my app is written in C and C++. I have access to them so building them to another format that iOS can use will not be an issue, but I'm not allowed to expose those code. Android has NDK that allows you to build all your native code into a `.so` lib. Does iOS have something similar?

Comment: It's not necessary, since Xcode already includes what you need. _"The powerful open-source LLVM compiler for C, C++, and Objective-C is built into Xcode and available from Terminal. "_.

Comment: @Michael does that mean ipa file cant be reverse engineered?

Comment: Compiling C or C++ to machine code does not protect against reverse-engineering on any platform, if that's what you were implying.

Comment: @Michael right, sorry, let me rephrase. does that mean ipa can only be reverse engineered to machine code?

Comment: @Michael machine code is enough to serve my needs

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C can interface to your C and C++ code directly - simply compile it along the rest of your app's code.

If you're using Swift, you can only access the C parts of your existing code directly. To use the C++ parts, you will need a (probably very thin) layer of Objective-C++ code as the glue between the two languages.

Comment: Any links to examples for this?